# Printing from polymorphic arrays

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am a student currently working on a project using polymorphism and arrays in Java. I have an array of Person objects of four subtypes: Undergrad, Grad, Faculty, and Staff. They all have instance variables like name, address, phone number, and birth date/hiring date. I want to select Staff members in the array, and print their toString() methods in the order in which those faculty members were hired.

Some stipulations:

only one array of person objects can be created (otherwise this wouldn't even be hard) nor can I use anything but a Person [] in this project.

I cannot use any methods of Array like the sort() method. I am only allowed to use a basic bubble sort algorithm.

here is the sorting algorithm I made, but this doesn't work right.

```
for (int index = 0; index < personArray.length; index++)
{
  int min = index;   

  for (int secondIndex = index+1; secondIndex < personArray.length; secondIndex++)
  {
      if (personArray[secondIndex] instanceof Staff)
      {

        if (((Staff)personArray[secondIndex]).getHiringDate().compareTo(((Staff)personArray[min]).getHiringDate())<0)
        {
            min = secondIndex;
        }
      }  
   }
   Person temp = personArray[index];
   personArray[index] = personArray[min];
   personArray[min] = temp;
   }
   for(int index = 0; index < personArray.length; index++)
     {
        if(personArray[index] instanceof Staff)
        {
        writer.print("\n" + personArray[index].toString());
        }
     }
```

I want to print  toStrings of Staff members by the Date that they were hired. How can I iterate through the array, find a Staff object, and then compare it to the next Staff object in the Array? The array has 100 elements and the order of Staff, Undergrad, Grad, and Faculty objects is random.

Answer (score 0):

I would bubble sort the array of Person at first. You don't need to distinguish, if the Person is Staff, Undergrad, Grad or Faculty. Just sort them all. After that, you could go thru the sorted array and print only Staff objects, like you are doing in

```
for(int index = 0; index < personArray.length; index++)
 {
    if(personArray[index] instanceof Staff)
    {
    writer.print("\n" + personArray[index].toString());
    }
 }
```